# Can a thread call SuspendThread passing its own thread ID?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Can a Windows thread suspend itself with `SuspendThread()`?

I can awake it from another one but, can it call `SuspendThread(GetCurrentThreadId())`?

Comment: Possibly, but why on earth would you do this? [`SuspendThread()` is designed for use by debuggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345.aspx), and [suspending a thread in this way has a very high chance of deadlocking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/09/55988.aspx). What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Except this is a thread suspending itself, meaning that it themselves can guarantee no locks are held etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this is possible, but with a slight alteration (see the cygwin mailing list discussing this [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-developers/2002-08/msg00033.html)):

```
SuspendThread(GetCurrentThread());
```

I also found MSDN saying a thread should only suspend itself, but it doesn't make it clear for me. I quote (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), emphasis mine):

> This function is primarily designed for use by debuggers. It is not intended to be used for thread synchronization. Calling SuspendThread on a thread that owns a synchronization object, such as a mutex or critical section, can lead to a deadlock if the calling thread tries to obtain a synchronization object owned by a suspended thread. To avoid this situation, **a thread within an application** that is not a debugger **should signal the other thread to suspend itself**. The target thread must be designed to watch for this signal and respond appropriately.

Comment: The reason for this is that when you suspend a thread, it doesn't do this in a "safe" manner. It just prevents the thread from running until it is un-suspended. Which means it won't release locks. If you signal a thread so it will suspend itself, then this suspension happens at a known, well-defined time. In other words, no such thing as not releasing a lock can happen. As an analogy, think of cancellation points in POSIX as opposed to terminating a thread.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `SuspendThread` on current thread. [Good read on the topic](http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/WRK/2009/01/what-does-suspendthread-really-do/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As a method of creating reusable threads for work tasks without the overhead of create and terminate tasks, suspend and resume thread could be used to quiesce a thread at the end of the task. When work is dispatch to the thread, resume it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).